# I need to set column B in a dataframe to null if column A is NULL

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

Given the following dataframe:

```
A    B   C
NULL 1   2
3    4   3
5    3   1
NULL 2   6
```

I'd like to replace the value in B with null if the A is null:

```
A     B    C
NULL  NULL 2
3     4    3
5     3    1
NULL  NULL 6
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.loc` for this.

Note that any column with `NaN` values becomes `float`, as `NaN` is considered a `float`.

```
df.loc[df['A'].isnull(), 'B'] = np.nan

print(df)

#      A    B  C
# 0  NaN  NaN  2
# 1  3.0  4.0  3
# 2  5.0  3.0  1
# 3  NaN  NaN  6
```